# Restricted permutations revisited!

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many ways can we arrange $n$ different things at $r$ places (each of $r$ places can have any of the $n$ things)**repetition allowed**,such that $2$ of the $n$ things are always included?

Foe example if **n=3**  lets say {2,3,4} and **r=3**  and(2,4) being compulsory,we have $12$ permutations:-

({2,4,4} {2,2,4} {2,4,2} {4,4,2} {4,2,2} {4,2,4} {2,4,3} {2,3,4} {3,2,4} {3,4,2} {4,2,3} {4,3,2})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** How many ways can you arrange $n$ objects at $r$ places, repetitions being allowed?

Of those, how many are bad? i.e. don't include at least one of the two compulsory numbers?

So, as you figured out, there are $n^r$ possible combinations. From these $(n-1)^r$ don't contain the first number and $(n-1)^r$ don't contain the second number. But we counted the $(n-2)^r$ combinations which don't contain both compulsory numbers into both $(n-2)^r$ so we need to add them back in. So our answer is

$$n^r-2(n-1)^r+(n-2)^r$$

Comment: Arranging n objects at r places is n^r.
Are the bad cases (2*(n-1)^r + (n-2)^r)??

Comment: @phineas And how many don't contain the first compulsory numbers? How many don't contain the second compulsory number?

Comment: @phineas Just be carefull with the fact that you subtract twice the ones which don't contain both compulsory numbers, you need to add them back in. In your example, you have $27-8-8+1=12$ sets...